# Library not working in iOS, getting a bunch of error? (SDWebImage)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, sdwebimage

I am having this issue while using SDWebImage not sure why but it randomly happened unless I did something that I do not understand, but when I compile I get around 40 errors that are based on the library. It was working before I changed some code back but not sure what happened as I tried to go back to that but it still errors. Anyone ever experience it or now how I can trouble shoot it?

I have the files for the lib.

Ok the errors are random, but this for example:

[image]

Expanding the errors says In file included folder/path/to/the/file

[image]

[image]

This is the deployment

[image]

Comment: How about posting the errors so people can offer help?

Comment: Error details should help all.

Comment: I added it above but it makes no sense

Comment: What is your base SDK version? What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: I added it above -- xcode version 5.1, and pods platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.6'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a typo in the SDWebImageManager.h and .h files. Specifically, it looks like you have a stray @ in there which you typed in by accident (or you "over deleted" something by mistake).

If you are using a git repo then you can fairly quickly find this by comparing the differences to an earlier version. Or use the merge tool from the Developer tools to compare you version of these files to the unchanged original.